# Python equivalent of Haskell's [1..] (to index a list)

Tags: python, list, loops, haskell

I have a list of elements in python. I don't know the number of elements in the list. I would like to add indexes to the list.

In Haskell, I could do the following

```
zip [1..] "abcdefghijklmnop"
[(1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c'),(4,'d'),(5,'e'),(6,'f'),(7,'g'),(8,'h'),(9,'i'),(10,'j'),(11,'k'),(12,'l'),(13,'m'),(14,'n'),(15,'o'),(16,'p')]
```

Now imagine that the string was of unknown size. This would still work in Haskell, and the integer list gives as many integers as necessary until the string runs out.

How would one do the equivalent in Python?

I have tried this:

```
s = "abcdefghijklmnop"
indexedlist = []
for i,c in enumerate(s):
    indexedlist.append((i,c))

>>> indexedlist
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'd'), (4, 'e'), (5, 'f'), (6, 'g'), (7, 'h'), (8, 'i'), (9, 'j'), (10, 'k'), (11, 'l'), (12, 'm'), (13, 'n'), (14, 'o'), (15, 'p')]
```

And it works, but I'm wondering if there is a shorter/cleaner way, since it is 4 lines of code and feels much.

Comment: BTW: you probably want: `enumerate(s, start=1)` for a direct equivalent. Moreover in the `itertools` module there is a `[n..]` perfect equivalent which is `itertools.count(n)` so you could translate the code to `zip(count(n), s)`.

Comment: For your n, wouldn't you actually put len(s) when you don't know n?

Comment: No. `count(n)` is "the same" as `[n..]` i.e. the infinite sequence of naturals greater or equal to `n`.

Comment: Oh, so n in this case would be  0 or 1 depending on how I want to index   (1 according to the given Haskell code)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just do `list(enumerate(s))`. This iterates over the `enumerate` object and converts it to a `list`.

Comment: I feel this is the far cleanest one so far, even if they all work. It also works for me on Python 2.7

Answer (score 6):

You can simplify it with a list comprehension:

```
>>> [i for i in enumerate(s)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `range` function with `zip`.

For Python 2:

```
>>> s = "abcdefghijklmnop"
>>> zip(range(16),s)
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'd'), (4, 'e'), (5, 'f'), (6, 'g'), (7, 'h'), (8, 'i'), (9, 'j'), (10, 'k'), (11, 'l'), (12, 'm'), (13, 'n'), (14, 'o'), (15, 'p')]
```

For Python 3:

```
>>> s = "abcdefghijklmnop"
>>> list(zip(range(16),s))
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'd'), (4, 'e'), (5, 'f'), (6, 'g'), (7, 'h'), (8, 'i'), (9, 'j'), (10, 'k'), (11, 'l'), (12, 'm'), (13, 'n'), (14, 'o'), (15, 'p')]
```

Comment: NB: This only works in Python 2, where `zip()` returns a `list`.

Comment: Since (in Python 3) `zip(range(len(s)) , s` is functionally identical to `enumerate(s)`, it looks like you've arrived at `list(enumerate(s))`. :P

Answer (score 2):

Using `enumerate` is definitely the way to go, but here is a little bit more functional solution with [toolz](https://github.com/pytoolz/toolz):

```
from toolz.itertoolz import iterate, zip
zip(iterate(lambda x: x + 1, 0), "abcdefghijklmnop")
```

Answer (score 0):

lists in Haskell are lazy, indeed, these could also work with an "infinite list".

Therefore a more semantically equivalent Python fragment would just be:

```
enumerate(l, start=1)
```

if you then enumerate over this result, it will enumerate over the list `l` and produce 2-tuples when necessary.